# Dracaena dying? Propagating

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, propagation, dracaena

I prematurely decided to propagate a *Dracaena*! My plant was growing rapidly as the weather was nice for a few weeks so I thought it would be a good time to propagate... 1 week later and it began snowing and the plant has gone back into hibernation

It looks like the severed stem is beginning to die? Is there anything I can do to try and encourage foliage to grow on this stem?

Would pruning the foliage on other stems encourage growth?

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: Checkout this other questions: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/56302/17229.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest just leaving it alone.  These plants bud out quite readily from old growth but usually need good light to power the new buds.  If you wait till spring there will be more light.

By spring you will also be able to evaluate how much of that stem has died back.  When it buds out you can cut it back to just above the new buds.